# iTwin or VPN: what is the difference?

Tags: mac, vpn

The company I work for has provided us with iTwins, to allow us to work from home. A friend of mine suggested that a normal VPN would be cheaper and safer.

Is this true? Does anyone have any experience with iTwin? Does my friend's claim mean that iTwin is not safe?